# Javascript exiting Loop Early

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a loop for a coin flipping program that I'm making. the problem is the it seems to be exiting early. Take a look.

```
$(function() {
    $('#rollDice').click(function() {

        var e = document.getElementById("diceSides");
        var diceSides = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var diceRolls = document.getElementById('rollCount').value;

        if (diceRolls.match(/^[\d]*$/ )) {      
            if (diceRolls == "")  {
                alert ("Please fill out all forms then try again.");

            } else {

                $('#diceRollContainer').slideDown('slow');

                for (i=0;i<diceRolls;i++) {
                    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*diceSides)+1;
                    var rolls = ("You rolled a " + diceSides + " sided die " + diceRolls + " times, and got the numbers ");

                    rollMinOne = rolls - 1;
                    if (i == rollMinOne) {
                        var rolls = (rolls + randNum + ".");
                    }
                    var rolls = (rolls + randNum + ", ");

                }
                alert (rolls);
            }
        } else {
            alert ("Make sure you only enter numbers and no spaces, then try again.");
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the program is alerting rolls before the for loop seems to be completed. Why is it doing this?

Comment: If you do console.log(diceRolls), what's the value of it?

Comment: What is it alerting, and what did you expect? Looking at that, I'd expect something like `You rolled a 4 sided die 3 times, and got the numbers 1, 2, 3.3, `

Comment: You rolled a 5 sided die 10 times, and got numbers 5,

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Would could I do to fix this? Also, why can't I comment on the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several bugs in that code, but the one that explains the behavior you're seeing is that you reset the value of `rolls` every time through the loop to the initial string.

Once you move that line out and you get a closer value, but you are also computing `rollsMinOne` from `rolls`, rather than `diceRolls`, as you intended (this is why choosing good names is so important), meaning that if statement is never true (since a string minus a number is the value `NaN` "Not a Number", which is not equal to *anything* [even itself!]).

Then the only functional (rather than style or design) problem is that you are then appending a value with a comma on the end even if you already added it with a period.

Putting it all together:

```
    var rolls = ("You rolled a " + diceSides + " sided die " + diceRolls + " times, and got the numbers ");
    for (i=0;i<diceRolls;i++) {
        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*diceSides)+1;

        rollMinOne = diceRolls - 1;
        if (i == rollMinOne) {
            rolls = (rolls + randNum + ".");
        } else {
            rolls = (rolls + randNum + ", ");
        }
```

Though as the other answers mention, there are easier and faster ways to get the same result, I feel it's important to understand why code doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I'm looking for, I want to understand it. Besides, it's just practice right now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

i got bored and implemented your code, this seems to work with minimal testing

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#rollDice').click(function() {

            var diceSides = $('#dice-sides').val();
            var diceRolls = $('#roll-count').val();

            if (diceRolls.match(/^[\d]*$/ )) {      
                if (diceRolls == "")  {
                    alert ("Please fill out all forms then try again.");

                } else {
                    $('#output').text(
                        "You rolled a " + diceSides + 
                        " sided die " + diceRolls + 
                        " times, and got the numbers ");

                    for (i=0; i<diceRolls; i++) {

                        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*diceSides)+1;

                        $('#output').append(randNum);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                alert ("Make sure you only enter numbers and no spaces, then try again.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <label>Sides</label>
    <input id="dice-sides" type="text" value="6">
    <label>Count</label>
    <input id="roll-count" type="text" value="1">
    <button id="rollDice">Roll</button>
</form>
Rolls
<div id="output"> 

</div>
```